# Android tableview cells not aligned

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am creating tables in Android Studio. The table header is created with the following code:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10">
        <TableRow android:background="@color/app_blue">

            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The table is inside the Recyclerview, the table is created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And table is shown like this:
[image: Emulator screenshot]

I colored the cells to make it easier to see the problem. How to align cells and header

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10">
            <TableRow
                android:background="@color/app_blue">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    ... />
                
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    
        
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here's what I changed and why:

Wrapping the entire layout in a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation to stack the header and RecyclerView vertically.

In the header TableRow, I added android:gravity="center" to center the text within each TextView.

For each TextView in the header, make sure to set android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1" to evenly distribute the available width among the columns.

You'll need to add similar TextView elements for all the columns in your header.